# Unable to deserialize struct ("value of type is not assignable to type")

Tags: json, go, serialization, yaml, deserialization

I'm running into an issue when trying to deserialize a struct.

I've tried using JSON and YAML, rewriting the struct to use a slice instead of a map (thinking it was an issue with my use of a map), all to no avail.

The struct below contains the issue, specifically the Deserialize function. I've replaced irrelevant code with `...`:

```golang
type Collection struct {
    Objects []Object `yaml:"objects,omitempty"`
}

...

func (c *Collection) Serialize() ([]byte, error) {
    return yaml.Marshal(c)
}

func (c *Collection) Deserialize(raw []byte) error {
    return yaml.Unmarshal(raw, c)
}
```

My test serializes a Collection, then attempts to deserialize the raw data from the first collection, into the second. It will then compare the two collections, but the issue presents itself during the deserialization:

```golang
func TestDeserialize(t *testing.T) {
    c := NewCollection()

    // NewRect creates a Rect (inherits from Object)
    c.AddObject(NewRect(10,10,NewPos(0,0))

    c2 := NewCollection()

    v raw, err := c.Serialize()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("collection 1 failed to serialize: %v", err)
    }

    // deserialize raw 1 into 2
    // this is the call that fails
    err = c2.Deserialize(raw)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("collection 2 failed to deserialize: %v", err)
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep running into:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[interface {}]interface {} is not assignable to type bw.Object [recovered]
    panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[interface {}]interface {} is not assignable to type bw.Object [recovered]
    panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[interface {}]interface {} is not assignable to type bw.Object
```

Edit:
I forgot to include the definition of `Object`. `Object` is a very basic interface:

```golang
type Object interface {
    Update()
    Draw()
    Serialize()
    Deserialize()
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Object`?

Comment: @BurakSerdar added Object definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work when you serialize because during serialization each element of the `Objects` array are structs. It will not work when you deserialize, because during deserialization, `Objects` is an empty array of interfaces. You cannot unmarshal to an interface, only to a struct, or value.

To fix this, you have to figure out the type of each individual array element in `Objects` during deserialization, and then deserialized based on the struct. There are multiple ways this can be done.

One way to do is to use a *fat interface*, a temporary struct containing all possible items:

```
type unmarshalObject struct {
   Type string `yaml:"type"`
   // All possible fields of all possible implementations
}

type unmarshalCollection struct {
    Objects []unmarshalObject `yaml:"objects,omitempty"`
}

func (c *Collection) Deserialize(raw []byte) error {
    var intermediate unmarshalCollection
    yaml.Unmarshal(raw, &intermediate)
    c.Objects=make([]Object,0)
    for _,object:=range intermediate.Objects {
        switch object.Type {
          case "rect":
             c.Objects=append(c.Objects,Rectangle{X1:object.X1,...})
          case "...":
           ...
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Error checking is omitted.

Same approach can be used with a `map[string]interface{}` instead of `unmarshalObject`, but that would require lots of type assertions.

Comment: I figured the answer would be something like this. Thank you. I'm sure I can find a better way to write my interfaces that won't require weird work-arounds like this.